Load remote React component in runtime
I could not find an good enough answer so I'm creating a new question with the details of what I'm trying to archive.
I have a React Component that will be embedded in other pages.
This React Component, which for now on I'll call Host Component, needs to dynamically load remote components on runtime. Essentially it makes a call for an API, on the answer there will be a URL for a CDN where the component it needs to render is at. I'm also the owner for these components that I will call Remote Components.
It really doesn't matter for me if these components needs to be a IIFE, UMD, CJS or ESM.
What I did so far
I've been abusing GPT for a solution but it only gotten me so far.
I tried to use lazy imports from React and build my Remote Components as ESM. The problem is that the built bundle file contains a React import that can not be resolved on runtime. Then I moved to UMD and started importing it by dynamically by creating a script tag with the path of my UMD Remote Component. Now it complains about "it can not read properties of null (reading useState)". GPT suggests that it happens because Remote Component and Host Application are using different React instances. And It makes sense because if I edit manually the bundle to replace react calls to window.react  on both Host Application and Remote Component it works just fine.
So I would like to hear your take on it. Does this approach makes sense at all?
I read about Module Federation (micro-frontend architecture) and It does make sense for me. But What I'm trying to archive is slightly different from what it proposes. Module Federation uses a server which a configuration of what area the modules it expects to export/import. I do not have such thing as the modules will be manage by another application.
Thanks you all folks!
EDIT
I've created a bit more detailed question on reactjs Reddit:
https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/1d9j292/import_remote_esm_module_react_component_from_a/

you can create MDX files with your components and load them from remote source (as string) using next-mdx-remote library.
